# Prove a summation equals to $n^n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!} n^{n-k} = n^n$$
I have tried induction but changing from $n$ to $(n+1)$ even further complicate the formula and no way to extract the case $n$ for substitution as $n^n$.  I also considered the binomial expansion of $(z+n)^n$ and differentiate it to obtain the $k$ in the summation.  But I can't eliminate the $1/k!$ at the denominator so as to match the original RHS.

Comment: [This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916925/how-to-show-sum-k-1n-binomn-1k-1-nn-k-k-nn?noredirect=1&lq=1) looks very similar to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} n^{n-k} k! = n^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916925/how-to-show-sum-k-1n-binomn-1k-1-nn-k-k-nn) - found using Sarvesh's comment above. Note $\binom{n-1}{k-1}k! = \left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\right)k! = k\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}$, so it's more than just similar, with it actually just being a version written somewhat differently.

Comment: Yes, the two are the same.  Thank you for the reference.