# Where does my counting argument fails (Counting of numbers with freshness $k$)?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Doing some recreational math, i was trying to reproduce the combinatorial proof of the identity

$$
n^n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\cdot k\cdot n^{n-k-1}\,\,\,\,(*)
$$

mentioned by OP in the Question [Non combinatorial proof of formula for nn
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361500/non-combinatorial-proof-of-formula-for-nn?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To be honest this shouldn't be too difficult:

the number of all sequences with length $n$ out of numbers $1,2,..,n$ is clearly $\underbrace{ n \cdot n...\cdot n}_{n\,\,times}=n^n$ which establishs the l.h.s. . For the r.h.s we demand that the first $k$ numbers are distinct but that the rest of the sequence can be choosen freely as before (Denote this number by $a_k$). In the end we sum over all $a_k$. I get

$$
a_k=\underbrace{n\cdot(n-1)...\cdot(n-k+1)}_{choose\,\,k\,\,numbers\\distinct}\times\underbrace{n^{n-k}}_{choose\,\,n-k\,\,numbers\\freely}\\=
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}n^{n-k} \,\,\,\,(**)
$$

But this is not the same then the terms under the summation sign in $(*)$ so what am i doing wrong?

---

**Edit 1:**

I think i got it, i have to discount for the sequences with $k'>k$ distinct numbers (they can still fall out of the random part of my product) .Is this correct?

---

**Edit 2:**

To finish this, the correct quantity is given by the difference of sequences with $k$ and $k+1$ distinct numbers:

$$
a_{k+1}-a_{k}=-\frac{n!}{n^{n-k}}\left(\frac{1}{(n-k-1)!n}-\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\right)=-\frac{k}{n(n-k)!}\frac{n!}{n^{n-k}}
$$

Done!

---

**Edit3:**

To avoid algebra we can also reason as follows (credit to @darijgrinberg):

Add to $(**)$ the following condtion: the $k+1$ number is fixed to ne one of the numbers in the first part of the product so that we don't get a  sequence with $k+1$ distinct numbers. There are $k$ possiblities. Afterwards we can choose all remaining $n-k-1$ numbers at our wish. This results in a  replacement $n^{n-k}\rightarrow k\times n^{n-k-1}$

Comment: You don't choose the last $n-k$ numbers freely. You have to make sure that the first of them violates the distinctness condition, i.e., equals one of the preceding $k$ numbers. That's where the $k$ factor will come from.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks: i was already suspecting that. See my edit!

Comment: @darijgrinberg do you have any idea how to see the last Formula (after edit) directly without resorting to annoying Algebra? Thx!

Comment: You don't have to subtract anything. Just fix your argument as I suggested in the first comment.

Comment: apart from the sign, edit 2 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell if you already figured it out, but in case you haven't:

$$
a_k = \underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot (n-k+1)}_\text{choose first $k$ numbers distinct}\times\underbrace{k}_{\begin{array}{c}\text{choose $(k+1)^{st}$ number equal to }\\\text{one of the first $k$ numbers}\end{array}}\times \underbrace{n^{n-k-1}}_\text{choose remaining numbers freely}
$$
The middle term must be $k$ because you need the "freshness" to be *exactly* $k$, meaning the first $k$ numbers are distinct, but the first $k+1$ numbers are not. Therefore, the $(k+1)^{st}$ number needs to be equal to one of the previous $k$.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactely what i added to my Question a few seconds ago. So now i have two different Proofs relying purely on combinatorics, cool!!! :)

Comment: @tired Indeed! Since you are doing this for recreation, let me mention one other connection. Let $f_{n,k}=\binom{n}k kn^{n-k-1}$, then the formula can be written $$n^n=\sum_{k=1}^n k! f_{n,k}.$$ This is interesting because $f_{n,k}$ has a combinatorial interpretation; it is the number of "rooted forests" (forest with a root in each component) on a set of size $n$ with $k$ components. This shows that a function can be described as rooted forest together with a permutation $\pi$ of the roots. The correspondence is: if $v$ is a not a root, $f(v)$ is its parent; if $v$ is a root, $f(v)=\pi(v)$.

Comment: this is cool indeed. I wish i would have done more of this stuff back at University. Another Thing that i found nice is to divide everything by $n^n$ and use Stirling. We then see that the probability to get sequences with freshness $k$ is given by $k/n$ for sufficently small $k/n$ ...

Comment: @tired That probability distribution is cool, too! Letting $X_n$ be the freshness, then $P(X_n/\sqrt{n}>t)\to e^{-t^2/2}$ as $n\to\infty$, so $X_n$ has an asymptotically Weibull distribution. Then $E[X_n]\sim \sqrt{n\pi/2}$, so in a random function, around $\sqrt{n\pi/2}$ elements will be contained in a cycle, meaning $f^m(x)=x$ for some $m$.